# Play Flare animation on button press

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a FloatingActionButton in flutter to share users profile. I want to show a small flare animation whenever user clicks on that button. I am using this code but the animation is being displayed. The animation file is Congratulations.flr

```
Tooltip(
                message: "Share with friends",
                child: new FloatingActionButton(
                  heroTag: null,

                  backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                  child: Icon(Icons.share),
                  onPressed: () {

                    FlareActor(
                      'assets/videos/Congratulations.flr',
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      animation: 'animate',
                    );
                    shareUserProfile();
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put the FlareActor outside the onPressed method in the place you will want it to appear and after that to start it on a state changed.

Below is a link to a good tutorial on how to do this

https://medium.com/flutter-community/better-animations-in-flutter-using-flare-an-experiment-bf9fa6c44f13

Hope this will be helpful for you.